# How to call a non-static method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

In my class "Server.cs", I want to access a textbox from a form. I tried using this code:

```
ServerWindow.WriteChatlog(encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead));
```

But I got this error:

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Chat_Server.ServerWindow.WriteChatlog(string)
```

ServerWindows.WriteChatlog(string text) looks like this:

```
public void WriteChatlog(string text)
        {
            textBox1.Text += text + Environment.NewLine;
        }
```

Now I tried doing that directly from where I was using ServerWindow.WriteChatlog method, but it didn't work.

They are both non-static

Comment: Your title doesn't match your actual question.

Comment: Without knowing the class you're in (& not the file name), or the members of that class, you won't get a really good answer.

Comment: Add more clarification

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `WriteChatLog` on an instance of the `ServerWindow` class. Ex:

```
ServerWindow servwin = new ServerWindow();
servwin.WriteChatlog(encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead));
```

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov that's what I figured, since he states in his question that they are both non-static. we'll see what he actually meant I suppose.

Comment: Agree since he is aware that the method is non static

Answer (score 1):

You must use `this.WriteChatlog(...)` or just `WriteChatlog(...)`.  This assumes you're calling the code from within the form's code.

Comment: +1 for recognising he may already have an instance... or be in an instance.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst It is hard to determine the asker's "level of understanding" regarding forms and references, so I'm just assuming the simplest probable situation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an actual instance of `ServerWindow` when you're calling `ServerWindow.WriteChatlog`.  The method either needs to be static: `public static void WriteChatlog(string text)` or you need an instance of ServerWindow: `ServerWindow serverWindow = new ServerWindow()`  I suspect the former is what you actually need.

Just like there are no instance methods on Console- everything is static.